# JQplot image using .jqplotToImageStr({}): rendering issues in IE(+9)

Tags: javascript, image, internet-explorer, rendering, jqplot

I am using following code that I found online to create an image of jqplot. It works great in Firefox and Chrome but the image messes up in IE(+9). The point labels and legends are all over the place.

```
// given the div id of plot, get the img data
var imgData = $('#Barchartdiv').jqplotToImageStr({});

// create an img and add the data to it
var imgElem = $('<img/>').attr('src', imgData); 

//window.open(imgData, "_blank", "scrollbars=0");
$('#img_div').append(imgElem); // append the img to the DOM
```

Any help/suggestions?Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your legends, but I fixed my point label problem here:

[jqplot pointlabels off position in IE9+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23635564/jqplot-pointlabels-off-position-in-ie9/23636942#23636942)