# jqplot pointlabels off position in IE9+

Tags: image, internet-explorer, save, jqplot

In IE9+, the point labels seem to only occupy the 4th quadrant of the chart (as if the entire chart was scaled down) when using jqplotToImageStr. The chart displays normally otherwise (within the page when divs are used for the labels I believe)

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by adding the css rule:

```
.jqplot-point-label {
    text-align: left;
}
```

this is because the toimage function has a handler for center aligned text (which is the default), which is causing things to be positioned incorrectly.

The culprit:

```
if ($(el).css('textAlign') === 'center') {
    templeft = left + (canvasWidth - context.measureText(w).width)/2  - transx;
}
```

In chrome the textAlign property actually comes up as -webkit-center, and is thus ignored.